# How to find a tangent line to a 2nd degree curve at some point?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose I have a curve $C$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$ given by a quadratic form in three variables $Q$. Suppose $Q(0,1,0) = 0$. I would like to find the tangent line to $C$ at $(0,1,0)$. Could someone please explain me how to do this?
Thank you very much.

Comment: $Q: ax^2+2bxy+cy^2+2dxz+2eyz+fz^2=0$, dehomogenize $y$: $ax^2+2bx+c+2dxz+2ez+fz^2$, now $(0,0)$ is a point on $Q$ so $c=0$. The linear term $2bx+2ez$ is the tangent cone, so if $Q$ is smooth which it is if it is non-degenerate, this is the tangent line.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland Is that mean that the tangent line is given by the equation $2bx + 2ez = 0$?

Comment: I just realized that you want to be able to compute the tangent at a point at infinity $t=0$), which occurs when one has an asymptote. Formula (2) in my answer works the same for points at infinity.

Comment: The polar line of a point on the conic is tangent to the conic

Answer (score 1):

If the equation of the curve is

$$\tag{1}ax^2+by^2+2cxy+2dxt+2eyt+ft^2=0$$

the tangent line in $(x_0,y_0,t_0)$ is given by equation:

$$\tag{2}axx_0+byy_0+c(xy_0+x_0y)+d(xt_0+x_0t)+e(y_0t+yt_0)+ftt_0=0$$

Setting $t=t_0=1$ for points which are not at infinity, we can say that curve with equation $ax^2+by^2+2cxy+2dx+2ey+f$ has this generic equation for the tangent at $(x_0,y_0)$ :

$$axx_0+byy_0+c(xy_0+x_0y)+d(x+x_0)+e(y+y_0)+f=0$$

The connection between (1) and (2) is that (2) is a generalized dot product associated with quadratic form (1), considered as a generalized norm.

A proof is rather easy if you are accustomed to the linear algebra formalism of quadratic forms. For example by writing (1) and (2) resp. under the classical forms $X^TAX$ and $X^TAX_0.$, then expanding $Q(X)=X^TAX$ into its Taylor form, we get :

$$Q(X+H)=(X+H)^TA(X+H)=\underbrace{X^TAX}_{Q(X)}+H^T\underbrace{2AX}_{Q'(X)}+H^TAH.$$

Comment: I just supressed a spurious 2 in the second and third formula.